# Cannot point always on a specific directory in tkinter file dialogue

Tags: python, tkinter, directory

When i open from a script the file dialogue i want to point in a defined folder

```
initdir = os.path.normpath(self.defaultPath)
root = Tkinter.Tk()
root.withdraw()
self.file_path = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(initialdir=initdir, filetypes=[("*.xml","*.HTML"))])
root.lift()
```

The problem is that it doesn't work the same in all Windows 7 systems.

The script opens a configuration file, reads the default folder and opens the file dialogue at the defined folder.
On some systems, if you choose a file from another folder, after exiting the script and run it again, it opens the file dialogue and it points at the last open folder.

Some of them respect the path of the defined default folder
I use python 2

I cannot understand why the same code behaviors differently in two windows 7 systems.

Could you please give me any suggestion ?

Comment: I discovered that if i choose the 'C:\', and after i choose again the default folder it works for ever. So something is triggered when i choose once the 'C:\' and the file dialogue points the right folder !

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem, the script reads the configuration file and if it is the first time launch, it opens the file dialogue in C:\
Then, the file dialogue opens always in the default folder.